# PHP and regex to convert "a" to "an" before a word starting with a vowel

Tags: php, regex, string, case, grammar

I was pretty surprised I couldn't find this anywhere online, including stackoverflow. I'm looking for the regex to use in the PHP function preg_replace to achieve this:

**Find any part of the text where " a " is followed by a vowel, and convert the " a " to " an ", following the English grammar rule.**

For example:

" a apple" will be converted to " an apple".

" a igloo" will be converted to " an igloo".

etc. etc.

Ideally, the function would be case-insensitive. What would be really impressive is if it could preserve the original case, e.g. "A" would be converted to "An", and the case of the next word would be left alone, e.g. "an American" wouldn't end up as "an american".

This seems like exactly the sort of thing a regex would be ideal for, and that a lot of people would find useful, but I can't figure it out. Would be grateful for some help with this.

I'm currently trying this:

```
preg_replace("/ a?i ([aeio])?i/", "an $1", $string)
```

As commenters have rightfully pointed out, this won't completely solve the problem of a / an, as that's based on sound and not just letters. However, I still think it's worthwhile on an "every little helps" basis, as it corrects the majority of such issues and so saves some human editing time.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Is this homework or a for-fun project? Because grammar is more complex than that. "A used book" shouldn't be "An used book." On the flip side, "A honest man" should become "An honest man."

Comment: The regex is `@"\ba\b (?=\b(a|e|i|o|u).*?\b)"` but its in `c#`..I think it would work.Replace it by `"an "`

Comment: Ah yeah, the u issue depends on whether or not it's pronounced "uh" or "yu", right? That's tricky. The only solution would be a big dictionary of such words, wouldn't it?

Comment: The use of `an` depends entirely on the phonetic sound, not the letter. For example: `An 8 legged creature`. What are you really trying to do here? Fix grammar with a regex? Why?

Comment: But in the majority of cases, if it's a vowel it's likely to be a sound that needs "an". I know this code won't make the text perfect, but it will save me some time editing some errors.

Comment: A better solution is to get these people to type in English?

Comment: *"This seems like exactly the sort of thing a regex would be ideal for"*... only for your literal goal (replace `a {vowel}` with `an {vowel}`, not for anything useful in real life as far as correcting grammar and spelling goes.

Comment: FWIW: [english.stackexchange/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Comment: Acronyms make it even more complex: e.g. "I sent her **an** SMS."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My pattern is as follows, though the issue (re: u) in the comments above is way trickier.

```
preg_replace('/\b(a)\s+([aeiou])/i', '$1n $2', $source_string);
```

Of course, you could take a gamble if u is the only trouble letter, and trust the source string in the case where u follows, simply remove it from the pattern: `/\b(a)\s+([aeio])/i`

Comment: It was *a* once in a lifetime opportunity... The letter *u* isn't the only problematic one.

Comment: It's _an honor_ to answer questions in SO.

Comment: Thanks, that does it.

Is this necessary to make it case insensitive?

preg_replace('/\ba ([aeioAEIO])/', 'an $1', $string);

We know that this doesn't solve the problem perfectly. As I said above, it's just to fix some of the errors. I'll still have to manually edit the results, this just saves a little bit of time.

Comment: Well it's certainly not `an` one size fits all solution.

Comment: I updated the answer for case insensitivity (use `i` modifier and 2 captures instead of one (in order to replace A with An as well)